# ¿Qué deberíamos hacer como comunidad cuando vemos comportamientos que pueden ser irregulares?

Tags: discusión, moderación, pregunta-específica, usuarios

Buenas, quiero poner mi preocupación frente a esta pregunta: [comando "\n" en JAVA no esta funcionando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/102576/227)

Problemas que encuentro:

- La pregunta no explica qué problema existe. Dice varias cosas, dice que ese código tiene problemas, pero no expone una forma de reproducir el problema.
- La pregunta tenía un voto a favor en menos de 5 minutos que fue creada. Un poco extraño, pero puede ser algo netamente circunstancial.
- La pregunta tiene un favorito. Esto me parece extraño puesto que, tal como luce, es un caso muy específico de un usuario. Pero ok, puede que haya alguien a quien realmente le parezca una pregunta muy interesante.

Luego de colocar en comentarios al OP que se necesita más detalle para comprender el problema, no edita la pregunta. Como sucede en algunas ocasiones, le das más vueltas al problema tratando de darle una solución, y al parecer el OP hizo eso y encontró una respuesta. La publicó y parece que con eso "anda". Nuevamente, su respuesta recibió un punto a favor en especie de "tiempo record" luego de ser publicada. Pero su respuesta parece ser muy específica y tiene más forma de una nueva pregunta ante el problema que enfrenta.

¿Qué deberíamos hacer como comunidad en estos casos?

Comment: Votar la pregunta negativamente si no es clara, a la respuesta si no es buena, dejar constancia en los comentarios, votar para cerrar si no es clara, reportar para que los moderadores lo revisen por si hay algunos usuarios compinchados... y evitar el efecto Meta :)

Comment: Parece un caso muy particular. No me parece que valga la pena buscar establecer una norma para algo que sucede una vez cada año. Mejor dediquemos este tiempo a revisar las colas de moderación.

Comment: vi el mismo caso en otras preguntas estos ultimos dias. no se me ocurrio tomar nota.. pero, voy a estar atento...

Comment: No se si suena a que tiene un cuenta clon que usa para votarse a si mismo

Comment: @toledano cualquier posible caso de uso de múltiples cuentas es importante. Reconocer estos casos o tener presente los posibles patrones es importante para la comunidad y sus moderadores. Lástima que pienses que no vale la pena, sobretodo cuando sucede más de una vez al año.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ sugiero que demos el beneficio de la duda, si es un caso particular pasará al olvido, pero si es un caso de múltiples cuentas demos tiempo a que le caiga el policia moderador jeje. Tú fuiste mod, estoy seguro que conoces bastante bien el proceso ;)

Answer (score 3):

## Normalmente nada.

No es responsabilidad de la comunidad el ocuparse de las cuentas marioneta. Ni tampoco tenemos las herramientas para hacerlo.
Es responsabilidad de los moderadores diamantados y/o los empleados de SO el ocuparse de las cuentas marionetas y disponen de las herramientas para hacerlo.

Si tienes evidencias firmes de que una cuenta es marioneta y está siendo usada violando los términos de uso de SO (nótese que las cuentas marioneta son admisibles si se usan correctamente) puedes marcar para atención de moderador una publicación de esta cuenta marioneta.
Pero ninguna de las cosas que mencionas es una evidencia firme. Todas son circunstanciales. Y alguna, como el recibir votos pronto, es deseable. Ojalá sucediese con mayor frecuencia. Por lo que en este caso particular yo no haría nada.

Comment: Muy bien planteado, Jose Antonio. El simple hecho de mencionarlo en Meta puede distorsionar la realidad, dando por ejemplo pistas a la supuesta cuenta marioneta. Reportemos silenciosamente y esperemos que los moderadores completen la investigación.

Comment: @fedorqui al menos alguien respondió. Y me alegra que alguien responda a diferencia de las personas que parecen ignorar el tema o peor aún, que crean que no es relevante.

Comment: En realidad tu respuesta se contradice, porque dices que no debemos hacer nada y luego dices "reportar para revisión de moderador". ¿Es así en realidad?

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ efectivamente, es un tema relevante. Sería interesante que, como antiguo moderador que eres, pudieras compartir algún detalle sobre tu experiencia al respecto: ¿hay muchos círculos de votantes (_voting rings_, no sé cómo traducirlo)? ¿funciona contactar con ellos? ¿se ha apercibido a mucha gente por este motivo?

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ En general no hay que hacer nada. En el caso particular que mencionas pienso que no hay que hacer nada puesto que no hay evidencias firmes. Y en el poco habitual caso de evidencias firmes reportar. Pero lo edito para dejarlo más explicito.

Comment: Imagino que eso lo dices como no moderador. En mi experiencia como moderador sí puedo decir que este tipo de cosas sí dan pie a estos casos. Usualmente un compañero de oficina o un amigo. De todas formas, los moderadores tienen herramientas que les permite hacer la investigación del caso y tener resultados concretos, fuera de indagar puntualmente entre 2 usuarios.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ Imaginas bien. Mi criterio no es mejor que el tuyo, reporta si lo consideras oportuno.